# Function in $L^1$ such that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \int_{B(x, t)} f(s) \; ds \neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function in $L^1$ such that
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \int_{B(x, t)} f(s) \; ds \neq 0?$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $B(x, t)$ denotes the ball of radius $t$.

Comment: No, because for an integrable function $f$, the measure $f\ d t$ is always absolutely continuous.

Comment: Too many $t$s in these formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. **Hint:** Use the dominated convergence theorem on the functions $\chi_{B(x,t)}f$.